# PHP wont update a VARCHAR field MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently having an issue where i have a database with the following columns

> ID | u_name | user_image | u_first | u_last | u_email | u_pwd | user_role | u_access

and i have the following code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET u_name = ?, u_first = ?, u_last  = ?, u_email = ?, user_role = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $user, $fname, $lname, $email, $userole, $ID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Now all other fields update the only one that wont is u_first

```
$fname = escape($_POST['fname']);
```

I've tried everything i can think of it used to work and no longer does,  yet when i try this query in the database directly it works?

Comment: It doesn't error out either

Comment: Did you also try quoting (`) the references? Usually when "a printed query works, but not in code" comes up, it's a question of something "translating" badly in the process, or server having different encoding (MySQL vs WWW-server).

Comment: @DocWeird I'll try that now